# How to prevent React from caching other github project pages

Tags: github-pages, service-worker, create-react-app

I built a GitHub User Page (`https://username.github.io`) with `create-react-app`. And I also have a project page at `https://username.github.io/myProject` which is built using Vuejs. The create-react-app seems to have a built-in service worker that does the caching automatically, which is what I wanted, but it also make my `https://username.github.io/myProject` not showing the project page correctly but showing my `https://username.github.io` page instead. I tried to unregister and clear the storage but it's only work once, when I located to my User's page and then to my Project's page, the problem still coming again.

How do I keep the caching behavior, and make these two urls able to show properly?

Answer (score 0):

When you register an SW at the root ("/") it automatically takes control of everything below it ("/myapp2"). This is bu design and there's no exclusion config available.

I think you have two options:

1. Move the React project out of the root to it's own sub dir and have the SE control only that
2. Write some logic in the SW itself that checks all fetches it's handling and does a no-op if the they match a dir you don't want to be handled by the SW